# Issue with window.navigator.systemLanguage String

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script to get the language of the browser and open the specific index localized

```
       var language = window.navigator.systemLanguage;

if (language == "it-IT" || language == "it-it" || language == "ita-IT" || language == "it-ITA" || language == "it" ||language == "IT" ||language == "ita" ||language == "italiano" || language == "italian")
{
    location.href = "index_it.html";
}
else{
    location.href = "index_esp.html";
}
```

unfortunately works only in Internet Explore but in Firefox and Chrome switch always on `index_esp.html` also with Italian Browsers

How to get the right language String ID? (If is this the cause of the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try both "systemLanguage" and "language":

```
var language = window.navigator.systemLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

It'd make your life easier to convert it to lower case too:

```
language = language.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: thanks! Seems that In IE works only `systemLanguage`  and in the other browsers `language`, otherwise the id of the language results undefined